# How to delete data from sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have created a table with three entries name,adress and phone no.
Now i want to delete data based on the name i type in the name text field. I successfully doing this but the problem is that if I type a name which is not in my database label still show 'contact deleted '... Here is my code

```
   -(void)deleteContact{
      const char *dbPath=[databasePath UTF8String];
      sqlite3_stmt *statement;
      if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
          {

    NSString *querySQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from 
                contacts where name=\"%@\"",name.text];
    const char *query_stmt=[querySQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt,-1,&statement, NULL);
        (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_OK); 

            status.text=@"Contact Deleted"; 
    name.text=@"";
    address.text=@"";
    phone.text=@"";

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    }
sqlite3_close(contactDB);

[name resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete is OK even if there is nothing to delete.
If you need to know if there is anything to delete you should check this.

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select count (*) from contacts where name=\"%@\"", name.text];
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int res = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (res != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"sqlite3_prepare_v2() failed");
    return;
}
int count = 0;
if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    count = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

if (count == 0) {
    // nothing to delete, do whatever you like
} else {
    // do real delete
    // your code for that seems to be OK
}
```

Comment: @MUKESH Don't mention it. Vote for answer which better suit you.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper Can you please post the correct code as I am getting prpare_v2 failed :( Thanks in advance

Comment: @Eshwar Chaitanya, do you understand you have to put correct SQL command in first line of code? sqlite3_prepare_v2 may fail if there is no such table 'contacts' or there is no such column 'name' in it and so on. Put applicable SQL command.

Comment: @ValeriyVan I have updated the code according to the table name which I had created and also I have a column name called "Name",but still I am facing the issue,Could you please lead me in the right direction,regards and thanks in advance :)

Comment: @ValeriyVan More over I took a model class to hold the variables,I haven't inserted any ID(pk) value.I have simply retrieved the ids from database using the statement sqlite3_column_text(statement,0);So I have subclassed for the view controller for display purpose.I mean for retrieving the database path as well as database.Hence I am using the statement "select count (*) from reminders where reminderInstance.reminderID=\"%@\", reminderInstance.reminderID];

Should I assign the primary key value to reminderID in model class or should I do some thing else.Please help me with your valuable sugg's

Comment: Please go through this link when ever you find some free time so that my issue sounds pretty much clear to understand:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802526/how-to-delete-corresponding-record-from-database-after-a-row-is-deleted-from-tab

Answer (score 2):

**delete from YourTable where name = "NameToDelete"**
will delete all records with field name equal to NameToDelete from table YourTable.

Comment: Thank you ,but my problem is even i type a name which is not in my database, status still show contact deleted.

Comment: Mukesh, maybe that's because "sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_OK" gives a positive result if the query you're firing is error free and is correct logic-wise. It doesn't check whether your query deleted any record or not. Your query is correct, so it returns OK status every time. Even during those times when you send a name which is not in your database, you're performing a correct operation.

Comment: I guess, you'd have to use some other flag instead of SQLITE_OK to set your status as 'Contact Deleted'.

Comment: Dip Dhingani,Can you please give me a code which sort out my problem...thank you.

Comment: I think in your case, after you've passed the delete query say for example name='xyz'. You've to pass a select query searching the same name. 

Something like this:
select * form contacts where name = "xyz"
and then check with flag SQLITE_NOTFOUND. This will return 12 when table or record is not found. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is what was written in sqlite3.h header file: 

#define SQLITE_NOTFOUND    12   /* NOT USED. Table or record not found */